# UV Texture oddity in textureUnits, openscenegraph

Tags: opengl, openscenegraph

I am having issues with textures. I have the model open as a .osg so I will refer to it here as such here. I have one texture in textureUnit 0 which acts as a base texture. Then I have a second texture in textureUnit 1 which acts as a label of sorts. I apply a rgba texture in there which then should be transparent on the model in openscenegraph. However I get this:

[image: img]

The gray areas are the base texture. The darker areas are where the uv coordinates move off the edge of the texture itself. I cant seem to be able to remove the dark areas. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the edge clamping mode -- the dark is probably some of the Texture Border color creeping in. Try setting GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE​ as your texture wrap mode.